# How to filter csv based on a keyword

Tags: magento, csv, import, filter

I have a csv file from a supplier with like 4000 products. I only want to add about 200 products from this supplier to my Magento database. What I would like to do is filter out all the products not containing my keyword and change to image name from 1234-567.jpg to product-name.jpg too. But right now I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible so I might not change the image name. But how do I filter out all the unwanted products?

Answer (score 0):

I would argue this isn't really a programming question, and thus doesn't belong on Stack Overflow.

Here is, however, an answer from SuperUser
https://superuser.com/a/827575

This would work for you on Linux or OSX.

If you are trying to do this using a programming language, I suggest restating the question in terms of that language, and tagging it appropriately.

Comment: Okay, I really don't know if it's a programing thing or not. thanks

Comment: No worries, just following the rules.  If the solution I posted helped you, please accept it as the answer.